# SharePoint list template - the splistitem being updated was not retrieved with all taxonomy fields

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem

I have created a list template using "Save as template" in SharePoint UI. My template contain three managed metadata field, among others. When using this template within the same site collection it works just fine, but when trying to use it in another site collection I get this error when saving an item:

*The splistitem being updated was not retrieved with all taxonomy fields.*

How do I use my list template across multiple site collections?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use global term sets rather than local term sets to make this across site collection.

In addition, per my test, if I add managed metadata in the list template, it will occur the error when i add a new list based on this template in other site collection:

[image]

If possible, could you share more information such as steps for further test.

Comment: As of my understanding every web collection has a hidden list called TaxanomyHiddenList. When you create a template (save as template) using an existing list containing taxonomy fields, every taxonomy field has a reference to that list.

<Field Type="TaxonomyFieldType" List="{TaxanomyHiddenList-guid}" ...

When you install this template on another site collection this reference will point back to the TaxanomyHiddenList in that site collection where you orginally created your template.

Can someone confirm? Is there a way to create a dynamic template where this reference isn't hard coded?